# Receive data in the nodejs server sent by the ajax jquery in a client

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am using ajax jquery to send the image to the nodejs server. But I am stuck up at receiving the image in the nodejs server from the client.

Client code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();    
formdata = new FormData();      
jQuery("#afile").on("change", function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    if (formdata) {
        formdata.append("image", file);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://130.211.245.190:8080",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function(){}
        });
    }                       
});
```

Can anyone help me to receive the image in the server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have this route `http://130.211.245.190:8080`? and i guess this would also do the same `/`.

Comment: in `node.js` what have you tried so far?

Comment: When deal with route, isn't necessary full URL, only the route. Example: /upload. Is wrong http://130.211.245.190:8080. Your app running in 8080 port? Do you can share the route and post method for more details?

Comment: I tried using xhr in the server side. But I was unable to receive multiple data using xhr.send(). So I tried Ajax. As I m not familiar with ajax, I dont have an idea how to receive multiple data in the sever side. Can you please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think "this" should be wraped "$()"...
You could try it...

```
jQuery.noConflict();    
formdata = new FormData();      
jQuery("#afile").on("change", function() {
    var file = $(this).files[0];
    if (formdata) {
        formdata.append("image", file);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://130.211.245.190:8080",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function(){}
        });
    }                       
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to receive the image on the server side(nodejs). Suggest some snippets

Answer (score 0):

To receive multipart/form-data in node you can use any of the following packages

[busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy)

[multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty)

[formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)

[multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

If you are using express probably you are using body-parser but this package does not handle multipart/form-data due to their complexity.

This is a sample taken from the multer docs

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
     // req.file is the `avatar` file
     // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

You can lookup the req.file or the req.files for the uploaded files and their information like file name size and destination. Also req.body will contain any text fields if the request contains any.

If you are using plain node you can try the others to see if they fit your needs. They usually allow for more control but are more dificult to configure.